# Change timeout on WebClient

Tags: vb.net, timeout, webclient

I need to change the timeout for a WebClient object.  I have a query I'm passing to retrieve a CSV that works through a browser URL but does not work in my .Net project.  It appears the client times out.  Here is the line...

```
ResponseText = Client.DownloadString("http://someBIwebquery.com")
```

The line executes, but ResponseText is nothing after.  I've passed other queries to the same server using the same method in the past, and again this does work when passed as a browser URL, so the issue is simply WebClient timing out.

Further complicating things, this object is already modified to accept cookies, so I already have an altered WebClient class I'm using:

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class CookieAwareWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    Private cc As New CookieContainer()
    Private lastPage As String

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim R = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        If TypeOf R Is HttpWebRequest Then
            With DirectCast(R, HttpWebRequest)
                .CookieContainer = cc
                If Not lastPage Is Nothing Then
                    .Referer = lastPage
                End If
            End With
        End If
        lastPage = address.ToString()
        Return R
    End Function

    Protected Overrides WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)

End Class
```

And I need to figure out a way to override the timeout request.  I've already found this C# code, but I'm having trouble translating it.  I'm not completely clueless when it comes to C#, but I'm missing something:

```
private class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            WebRequest w = base.GetWebRequest(uri);
            w.Timeout = 20 * 60 * 1000;
            return w;
        }
    }
```

That's what I've got for now, if anyone can give me a clue, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Man I feel dumb....

Anyway, after looking at this more closely, I figured out what I needed to do.  I'd normally delete a question like this, but since I just figured out what I was missing and it was hard to find, I'm going to go ahead and post the answer.

I just needed to add these lines to my class:

```
Property Timeout As Integer  '(I actually did this the "proper" way, but this would be sufficient.)
```

and in the Override for GetWebRequest:

```
R.Timeout = Me.Timeout
```

That's pretty much it.  Here's the class in its entierty:

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class CookieAwareWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

    Private cc As New CookieContainer()
    Private lastPage As String

    Private _Timeout As Integer
    Public Property Timeout() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Timeout
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Timeout = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim R = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        R.Timeout = Me.Timeout
        If TypeOf R Is HttpWebRequest Then
            With DirectCast(R, HttpWebRequest)
                .CookieContainer = cc
                If Not lastPage Is Nothing Then
                    .Referer = lastPage
                End If
            End With
        End If
        lastPage = address.ToString()
        Return R
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

For other users stumbling upon this answer, who may not need to add custom cookie handling, there is an easier way to change the timeout.

In my projects, I've used this snippet, which is much simpler:

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
request.Timeout = 10 * 60 * 1000 ' 10 minutes
```

No custom classes needed (they already exist).